# constructor Account in class Account cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, class, account

i keep getting this error in my AccountTest.java

here are my Account.java, and AccountTest.java, respectively:

https://gyazo.com/6933c02e50e08353087b0dd37d69eb2d
https://gyazo.com/8fbd1c514fdc3373d227ab6a34e151b0

I've been trying to figure this thing out for hours, please help! thanks!

Comment: lol Gerald copy paste your coding here. Like actually copy paste it here. No pictures

Comment: and also copy paste the actual error you see in console

Answer (score 0):

Your Account constructor expects 2 double-type arguments. You're only passing in one.